# Looking for MVC 3 tutorial with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking a tutorial that shows how to invoke an MVC action and pass parameters.
I have a dynamic "comment box" which I need to save to database. 
I want to use jQuery to send the comment data to a REST method that will handle it.

I also need to refresh part of a page with data returned by MVC action.
The data returned as JSON.

I have seen tutoral from Scott Guthrie, but that uses postback.
I need asynchronous communication through jQuery.

Very simple and small tutorial will be very useful.

Thanks

**Edit:**
I will be using `$.ajax()` calls of jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a form on your view that will allow the user to post a comment:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Comment", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "commentForm" }))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comment)
    <input type="submit" value="Comment" />
}
<div id="result"></div>
```

you could AJAXify it using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#commentForm').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // refresh some part of the DOM based ion the result
                $('#result').html(result.someProperty);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and a controller action which will save the comment and return a JSON object which could be used in the success callback:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string comment)
{
    // TODO: save the comment
    return Json(new { someProperty = "some value" });
}
```

And [here's a tutorial](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx) about progressive enhancement with ASP.NET MVC 3 and jQuery.

Comment: There is no separate form. I dynamically add a textbox with "post" and Cancel button. Clicking "post" button will call a js function to post. Your response has the thing I need. Let me try it out.